# Nuxt3 and Firebase: setDoc completely ignored by code

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm having a super weird issue with Firebase and Nuxt3.

When I'm on my register page and click register, I want to create a user with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, on the then I add some new information to the user, like the current theme, initials, etc. and I want to save them to a collection on firestore, so I run `setDoc` with all the data, but it doesn't run and doesn't return any error or logs, all logs show up except the `then/catch` of `setDoc`.
The weird thing is, if I move `setDoc` with some manual data to outside `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, it works perfectly fine.

I've changed the code a bit so it shows only the issues and used manual data, this is the code that currently ignores `setDoc` (Edit: forgot to mention, I commented absolutely everything else inside `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and left only `setDoc`, still doesn't work):

```
const register = (email, password, displayName) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(nuxtApp.$auth, email, password)
        .then((res) => {
            //...
            setDoc(doc(nuxtApp.$firestore, "users", "somerandomid"), {hello: "world"})
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("DONE FIRE")
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
            //...
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error)
        });
})
```

This code, where `setDoc` is exactly the same but outside of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, works perfectly fine:

```
const register = (email, password, displayName) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(nuxtApp.$auth, email, password)
        .then((res) => {
            //...
            //...
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error)
        });
    setDoc(doc(nuxtApp.$firestore, "users", "somerandomid"), {hello: "world"})
        .then(() => {
            console.log("DONE FIRE")
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
})
```

Any idea why this could be happening?